# Understanding malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I was given this piece of example code on a lab and I'm trying to understand it

```
int size = 5;
int **ppi2 = (int **) malloc(size * sizeof(int *));
```

Here's my breakdown of it as of now:

In order to allocate sufficient memory, we must multiply the number of things we want to allocate memory for (size) by the size of those things (sizeof(int *)).  That much is straightforward and makes a lot of sense.

I understand that we have to cast the result of malloc into a double pointer, since malloc returns bytes and the variable is a double pointer, but why are we setting ppi2 equal to the result of malloc in the first place?  Does it make ppi2 point to the spot in memory that we just allocated?

Comment: First of all, [do not cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: I'm programming in straight C, so I think I'm supposed to cast it

Comment: You need to cast the result in `C++` but not in `C`. Just read the accepted answer in the provided link.

Comment: I did, I misread it and got it swapped around.

Comment: The above is better written as `int **ppi2 = malloc(size * sizeof *ppi2);` (and `size` should probably be called something like `count`).

Comment: When doing multiplication on `malloc()`'s argument, beware of integer overflows.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't "return bytes", it returns a `void*` which refers to a memory location.  In C, a `void*` can be implicitly and safely converted to any other type of pointer, so no cast.

Answer (score 3):

With [malloc](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/lib_ref/m/malloc.html), you pass as a parameter the number of bytes of memory you want to allocate and it returns the address to the beginning of the memory you just allocated. With that address stored in a pointer, you can then do what you must with it. It does not return the bytes of memory, it returns the address so you can then go and manipulate them. That's why C memory management is important to grasp (you somehow lose that address, you "lose" the memory).

If you want to get a better understanding of how `malloc` works with the memory and its relationship with your program (which I recommend since its fundamental knowledge), read [Chapter 13](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/vm-api.pdf) of the [Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) operative system book. It's short, it's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that we have to cast the result of malloc into a double pointer, since malloc returns bytes and the variable is a double pointer...

[Do not cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2455888).

> why are we setting ppi2 equal to the result of malloc in the first place?

To point to the same location as by the pointer return by the `malloc`.

> Does it make ppi2 point to the spot in memory that we just allocated?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that we have to cast the result of malloc into a double pointer, since malloc returns bytes and the variable is a double pointer,

malloc doesn't return the bytes; it returns a pointer  that points into the bytes it allocates. This pointer has a generic pointer type `void *`. In C++ you must cast this `void *` back into the pointer type of your variable but in plain C this cast is optional.

> but why are we setting ppi2 equal to the result of malloc in the first place? Does it make ppi2 point to the spot in memory that we just allocated?

Yes.

Comment: In C++, it's usually better to use `new` rather than `malloc` -- or, better, to use one of the standard container classes.

Comment: @KeithThompson poor poor `allocator`s, no one never remembers them :D . The "real" C++ way of allocating / deallocating memory .